# Can I use Mock Server for load testing?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, performance-testing, load-testing, nock

We have a Legacy monolith application which we are breaking down into Microservice. The Monolith application has three endpoints:-

```
POST: /create
PUT: /verify
PUT: /dependents
```

As part of the flow the user first hits **/create**, then **/verify**, then **/dependents** and then makes call to **/activate** endpoint exposed by one of our microservices.

The microservice then makes call to another endpoint (**/validate**) exposed by the legacy application and returns the response to user.

The response time of legacy application is almost constant.

Would it be a good approach to mock the legacy application's (**/validate**) endpoint with approx delay for load testing?

We wish to avoid the initial three rest calls to the legacy application as a setup phase and directly hit the Microservice's (**/validate**) endpoint?

I wish to understand the Pro's and Con's of using a mock server for performance test.

Comment: Using nock server :- 

[NockServer](https://github.com/nock/nock)

Comment: Is the new microservice written in Node? Nock is not a mock server, it mocks server requests on the client side in Node processes.